# wpf, Datagrid, one column is based on three others

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I try to bind my observablecollection to datagrid. I want to make last column to be based on three others `(column[n] = column[x]*column[y]*((column[z]+100)/100))` something like this. My first aproach was to make property with calculations in get section but just cant make `UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged` to work. It updates values only when I go to another row. Second aproach was to bind last column i xaml to those three with calculations in multiconverter but dont know how to make that binding to work.
I think that first aproach is better, so could somebody tell me why `UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged` dont work, is there some kind of trick to make it working?

EDIT

```
long ilosc;
public long Ilosc { 
    get { 
        return ilosc; 
    } 
    set {
        ilosc = value; Console.WriteLine("ilosc"); NotifyPropertyChanged("CenaBrutto"); 
    } 
}
float cena;
public float Cena { 
    get { 
        return cena; 
    } 
    set {
        cena = value; Console.WriteLine("cena"); NotifyPropertyChanged("CenaBrutto"); 
    } 
}
float vat;
public float Vat { 
    get { 
        return vat; 
    } 
    set {
        vat = value; Console.WriteLine("vat"); NotifyPropertyChanged("CenaBrutto"); 
    } 
}

public float CenaBrutto {
    get {
        return Cena * Ilosc * ((Vat + 100) / 100); ; 
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property) {
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

and xaml code

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=fRoot, Path=Items, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="dgTU" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so could somebody tell me why "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"
>   dont work

You are misunderstanding the purpose of `UpdateSourceTrigger` in whole, and `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` in particular.

In data binding scenario, the binding source is an object, who provides a data value for data binding. On the other hand, the binding target is an object, that uses a value, which was provided by binding source.

Typical data binding use-case in WPF assumes, that view model is a binding *source*, and  control is a binding *target*.

`UpdateSourceTrigger` sets the mode for updating binding *source* (view model in the sample), while your problem is related to updating of *target* (`DataGrid`).

> is there some kind of trick to make it working?

There's no magic.
Your view model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and you have to raise `PropertyChanged` event for your calculated property, when one of the related properties has changed it's value. Here the sample:

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set 
        {
            if (a != value)
            {
                a = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("A");
            }
        }
    }
    private int a;

    public int B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set 
        {
            if (b != value)
            {
                b = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("B");
            }
        }
    }
    private int b;

    public int C
    {
        get { return c; }
        private set
        {
            if (c != value)
            {
                c = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("C");
            }
        }
    }
    private int c;

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        // update calculated property
        if (propertyName == "A" || propertyName == "B")
        {
            // this will cause binding target to re-read C value
            C = A + B;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**.

If your calculated property looks like this:

```
public int C
{
    get { return A + B; }
}
```

i.e., there's no setter, than it is enough to call `OnPropertyChanged("C")` after changing values of `A` or `B`:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    // other stuff
    // update calculated property
    if (propertyName == "A" || propertyName == "B")
    {
        // this will cause binding target to re-read C value
        OnPropertyChanged("C");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**.

Note, that you're using `DataGrid` with `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` (this is by default). Data binding expressions in this case also use the defaults, and for `DataGridTextColumn` (which will be generated for `float` properties) `UpdateSourceTrigger` is `LostFocus`. Your suggestion is right.

The solution is to turn `AutoGenerateColumns` to false, and set the desired `UpdateSourceTrigger` mode by hand:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=fRoot, Path=Items}" Name="dgTU" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Ilosc, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cena, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Vat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CenaBrutto}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

P.S. A little note. Do not use floating-point types (like `float` or `double`) for money calculations, use `decimal` instead.

Comment: I have "INotifyPropertyChanged" and all the stuff, calculations are made in get part of C property. The problem is, that all changes in datagrid are transfered to my properties when I leave row, just like "UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus" and I wanted it to work (like I saw in many many other threads) immediately

Comment: @RadosławMalinowski: this is because you're not raising `PropertyChanged` for `C`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry for not pointing it out corectly. In your update, U got exactly what I have in my code. And the code worked fine as I said before. But it updates C in datagrid only when I leave row. I have consolewritelines in setters of my properties and it fires when I leave row of datagrid

Comment: ok first, thanks for this "P.S. A little note. Do not use floating-point types (like float or double) for money calculations, use decimal instead."
second, autogeneratecolumns false did the trick, but, isnt it little confusing that setting "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" for entire datagrid (when autogeneratecolumns is true) dont work?

Comment: @RadosławMalinowski: no, there's nothing confusing here. `UpdateSourceTrigger` is a property of particular binding expression. `DataGrid` hasn't any customization for `AutoGenerateColumns` mode. In your initial XAML, you've set `UST` on `ItemsSource` property of `DataGrid`. This doesn't have any sense, because `DataGrid` cant't update its `ItemsSource` (it updates only *content* of `ItemsSource`).